# Java - Difference between private and package-private enum constructor

Tags: java, constructor, enums, private, package-private

Recently I'm quite oftenly using Enumerations. So I wonder...

Is there any difference between a private Enum constructor and a enum constructor withour any visibility modifier (package-private)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to java [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

> The constructor for an enum type must be package-private or private access.

but Accroding to the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.3)

> If no access modifier is specified for the constructor of an enum type, the constructor is private.

So there no difference between the  package-private and private .

Answer (score 4):

The constructor for enums is implicitly `private`, just like methods for interfaces and annotations are implicitly `public abstract`.  The default is package local for class members.

BTW enum classes are implicitly `final` and nested enum classes are implicitly `static`.

Older constructs tend to allow you to add implicit modifiers, but newer constructs don't allow you to say. e.g. enums are final but you can't add `final` to an enum.

Comment: I thought the default was package local, but once you start list all the combinations, you find it is more the exception than the rule.  A bit like "i-before-e-except-after-c" which has some many exceptions. The rule holds for common words/cases.